# put object in arraylist and create new object

Tags: java

Hello I have a application where I draw stuff clicking left mouse, when triggering right mouse It needs to go in the ArrayList and create a new Object. and when I start clicking left mouse again it has to continue withing the new object keep showing the other object.. my problem is that the old one disappears. can anyone look what i've forgot?

here is the code

```
Drawing draw; // class definition
private ArrayList<Drawing> tekening = new ArrayList<Drawing>();

public DrawingPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE); // zorg voor een witte achtergrond.
    this.addMouseListener(this); // control de mouselistener
    draw = new Drawing(color);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    draw.draw(g);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        Point k = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
        draw.addPoint(k);
        System.out.println("punt gezet op " + k);
    }
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
        tekening.add(draw);
        color = new Color(r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1) + 0, r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1) + 0, r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1) + 0);
        //System.out.println("new color " + color);
        draw.setColor(color);
        draw = new Drawing(color);
    }
}
```

---

I forgot the foreach loop in my paintcomponent.

```
        for(Drawing draw : tekening) {
        draw.draw(g);
    }
```

Comment: I see the problem with `addPoint()`...can you post the code for this method?

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
draw.setColor(color);
draw = new Drawing(color);
```

You are destroying the reference to the "old" drawing object.  If you want both to stay up there you need to create some concept of old and new in your application.  Maybe a `Map<Drawing,List<Drawing>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.  In it, you only redraw the current `draw` object.  When you complete one with the right mouse button and initialise a new one, it contains no info on the previous objects and thus nothing is drawn.  You `paintComponent(Graphics g)` should look like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(Drawing dr : tekening) {
        dr.draw(g);
    }
    repaint();
}
```

This loops over all `Drawings` painting each one of them.

Comment: Is it not more efficient, to not redraw everything each time and just leave the old drawings alone, while only manipulating the "newest" one?  Imagine a scenario with 2 trillion drawings.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Absolutely agree.  I was barely pointing out why the undesired behaviour occurs, not trying to write the most efficient code.  On another note, you'll most likely run out of memory well before you reach 2 trillion drawings.

Comment: Calling `repaint` in the `paintComponent` increases cpu usage and is not advisable. Instead repaint only on change i.e call it on mouse click

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati I agree with you; the main point of my answer is to demonstrate why the original problem exists, not to try to optimise the answer for performance.